# increase max_allowed_packet size in mysql docker

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, max-allowed-packet

We are using **Docker** for mysql, We are facing the below error while running

```
Packet for query is too large (12884616 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (12884616 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

now we need to increase `max_allowed_packet` size in **mysql** configuration, Can anyone help me on docker command to increase `max_allowed_packet`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

As an argument to the container command:

```
docker run -it -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql:5.7 --max-allowed-packet=67108864
```

See "Configuration without a cnf file" at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/, copied here for posterity:

> Configuration without a cnf file Many configuration options can be
>   passed as flags to mysqld. This will give you the flexibility to
>   customize the container without needing a cnf file. For example, if
>   you want to change the default encoding and collation for all tables
>   to use UTF-8 (utf8mb4) just run the following:
>
> $ `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
>
> If you would like to see a complete list of available options, just run:
>
> $ `docker run -it --rm mysql:tag --verbose --help`

When using `docker-compose` (as asked in the comments), add a `command` key with the arguments:

```
version: "3"
services:
  data:
    image: "mysql:5.7.20"
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856      # Set max_allowed_packet to 256M (or any other value)
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Comment: Any help in docker compose file  ?

Comment: Do I have to rebuild with the docker-compose file? or What should I do next? run `docker-compose down` and then `up` again?

Comment: @TanDat yes, you will need to reconfigure the service using `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` like you stated.

Comment: I find it essential  with sql imports to also ensure proper connection and database encoding. For that it's best to change command to this: `command: [ "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "--init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'", "--max-allowed-packet=67108864" ]` and add another environment parameter: `- LANG=C.UTF-8`

Answer (score 28):

When using `docker-compose` (as asked in the comments), add a `command` key with the arguments, for example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  data:
    image: "mysql:5.7.20"
    # Set max_allowed_packet to 256M (or any other value)
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Whilst this works for the MySQL docker images, it may not work for all is it overwrites the default command.

More info: [Docker Compose - Command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)

Comment: It works in my docker compose file. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you should modify it in your Dockerfile like this :

`RUN sed -ire 's/max_allowed_packet.*=.*/max_allowed_packet = YOURVALUE/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf`